# Convert fingerprint template to a .txt file

Tags: fingerprint, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-developer-api

My app requires me to store fingerprint templates and convert them into .txt files, but the Android M API only allows the developer to authenticate the current user against the user of the device.

Are there any other API s which can be used to meet my requirements?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, Android M or Samsung or iPhone APIs only allow to verify current user against user of device.

With Android M or Samsung or iPhone APIs you **can't get** fingerprint template or image.

There's some fingerprint scanners compatible with Android Platform and with SDK for Android. These SDKs allow to get fingerprint image or template. Scanners are plugged on USB port so you can't charge tablet and use fingerprint scanner simultaneous. For instance:

- http://www.dermalog.com/en/products_solutions/fingerprintscanner/
- http://www.futronic-tech.com/product_fs80h.html
- http://www.crossmatch.com/authentication-hardware/

There's also some devices with integrated fingerprint scanner and with SDK to get fingerprint image or template.